# execvp function with arguments does not work

Tags: linux, exec, execvp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

char** get_env(void){
    char *ptr, *ch, *next_ptr;
    char **tok = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 20);
    int i = 0;

    ch = getenv("PATH");
    for(i=0, ptr=ch; ;ptr=NULL,i++){
        tok[i] = strtok_r(ptr, ":", &next_ptr);
        if(tok[i] == NULL) break;
    }
    tok[i] = NULL;
    return tok;
}

char **get_input(char *input){
    char **command = malloc(8 * sizeof(char *));
    char *separator = " ";
    char *parsed, *nextptr;
    int index = 0;

    parsed = strtok_r(input, separator, &nextptr);
    while(parsed != NULL){
        command[index] = parsed;
        index++;
        parsed = strtok_r(NULL, separator, &nextptr);
    }

    command[index] = NULL;
    return command;
}

int main(void) {
    char **env = get_env();
    pid_t pid;
    int stat_loc;

    while(1) {
        int i = 0;
        char *nextptr, *parsed;
        char *command[20];
        char* input = malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
        printf("$>");
        input = fgets(input,19,stdin);
        input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';

        if(strcmp("exit",input) == 0) {
            free(input);
            break;
        }
        parsed = strtok_r(input, " ",&nextptr);
            while(parsed) {
            command[i] = parsed;
            printf("%s \n", command[i]);
            i++;
            parsed = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &nextptr);
        }
        command[i] = NULL;  

        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0){
            if(execvp(command[0], command) == -1) {
                printf("FAILED \n");
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        if(pid > 0){
            wait(&stat_loc);
        }

        free(input);
    }
    free(env);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to write a simple linux shell program in C. `execvp` function is being used.

when `command[0](char *)` and `command(char * [])` is entered to `execvp`, return value is only `-1`, it doesn't show running program such as `pwd`, `ls`.

I searched several blogs and manuals in web, but i can't find how to solve this error.
How can i make execvp function work?

---edited---

when i input `ls -a` in `char* input` variable, `strtok_r` function devide the string to pointer array(`char * command[]`), and command(`command[0]`) and argument(`command`) is entered `execvp` function.

i want to execute appropriate program such as `cd`, `pwd`, `ls`. But i cannot see program running, "FAILED" is only shown.

Comment: Provide a [mcve].

Comment: You never call `get_input()`, why did you include it in the question?

Comment: If `execvp` returns, you should use `perror()` to print the reason, not just `FAILED`.